# What is known about this independent set generalisation?

Tags: graphs

An applied problem I am working on could be modeled as the following problem on graphs:

> Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k>0$, find the largest set $S\subset V^k$ such that for each $A\in S$ the induced subgraph $G[A]$ is connected and such that no two $A_1, A_2\in S$ are adjacent in $G$.

For $k=1$, this is just the independent set problem, but for $k>2$ there doesn't seem to be any material on this generalisation.  Is this a known problem?  If yes, what is it called?

I am also interested in the case where instead of a single $k$, we have a multiset $K=\{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n\}$ and we want to decide if an $S=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\}\subset2^V$ with the aforementioned properties exists such that $|A_i|=k_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.